# Find actual probability in multiclass classification problem and use that to reject the data which does not belong to any class?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, classification

I am trying to perform CNN classification and used the probability at the end to decide to which class the model belongs but I also want to reject the data which does not belong to any of the class saying data don't belong to any of the class on which model is trained.

For rejecting the data I want to use the probability like for example if probability is less than 60 reject it by saying does not belong to any class. Is this thing possible?

I thought of using softmax at the end will give me the probability and I will use that probability to reject the data if it does not belong to any class but it seems it is assigning high probability to even to those data points (image) which does not belong to any of the class of the model on which it is trained on. So please provide some insight. I am new to this

Comment: Can you show an example of your output? Say if you have 10 classes, does your model output 10 probabilities (which sum up to 1) and one of those probabilities is high (for example > 0.6) even though the picture does not belong to that class? Is that correct?

Comment: yes exactly, the main idea behind this question, that I want to know is it possible to reject any unknown class based on the probability as that unknown class model has not seen it during training so I want to classify it as an unknown class. I will try to show the output for some reason i am not able to locate my datsets.